# Using Xdebug with PhpStorm to debug a WordPress project

Tags: wordpress, phpstorm, xdebug

I configured Xdebug to work with PhpStorm and XAMPP.

The Xdebug use port 9000 to listen to debug connections and I use Chrome with debug extension.

The connection between the browser and PhpStorm works but I don't understand why I can't only show the result of my breakpoint ?

[image: screenshot]

On this screenshot, I want to debug the `$sql` and `$wpdb` variables but PhpStorm start to open other pages and in the debugegr console I can't see the result of my breakpoints.

I will really thankful if someone can explain me how it works.

The project is really so slow and I have to use Xdebug.

Comment: It's a bit hard to say without knowing your setup (Xdebug & PhpStorm settings). But... **1)** You may have "Break at first line..." option checked in PhpStorm settings (so it will break on first line in the script that you execute); **2)** May may have configured Xdebug to try to debug every single script without the need for "debug me" flag (sometimes a person cannot configure Xdebug properly, leaves that option enabled, writes some tutorial/answer and it may be copies by other users without knowing what it actually do) -- that's excluding specific cases where such option actually needed.

Comment: **3)** On your screenshot you have 4 debug sessions (although it's possible that other 3 have already been closed and you just kept them there). This also hints on #2 (see above), especially looking at your `ajax.php` name (but then, it depends what exactly you are trying to debug). **4)** It's a WordPress project and WP (as well as any website that uses AJAX) can do multiple requests in background. Those other/unwanted debug session might be from such requests. Try adding those files (entry points)  to the excluded list (called "Skipped Paths").

Comment: **5)** WP, as well as any modern/popular framework have an entry point (`index.php`) which is used when request is handled for "nice URL" and not exact script/file name. You may have initial call for such URL + other (often multiple) calls on the same page to such extra resources (e.g. dynamic content (AJAX), script that combines your multiple CSS/JS files in 1 bundle, 404 requests). For example, the most common case for such "why the same script gets called twice" situation is 404 handler for the missing favicon.ico.

Comment: Now.. Xdebug browser helper/extension -- all what it does it sets the Xdebug COOKIE that lives until browser is closed (or you trigger it off). Such cookie by default will be sent with every subsequent request to the same domain:port (e.g. AJAX requests) .. which allows to actually debug them. In some cases though (where Angular/React/etc frameworks that implement own requests handling) such cookie may be stripped or not sent at all. **Overall** you need to better describe your setup/what exactly you are trying to debug and how you are doing this to get any more specific suggestions.

Comment: thank you for your answer, yes i have Break at first line activated, should i change phpstorm config ?  can you provide a good documentation about xcode utilisation please?

Comment: 1) https://learnxdebug.com/ 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/debugging/ 3) https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/debugging/ 4) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GokeXqI93x8 5) https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/

Comment: thank you so much :)